# I need to add a text value to an self closing empty tag, using XSLT

Tags: xslt

Please see the below XML. In the XML the name element is a self closing empty tag. I need to add a text value to this name element tag. This chunk of XML code might be repeated any number of times in the whole XML.

```
<participant typeCode="LOC">
  <participantRole classCode="SDLOC">
    <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
    <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
    <playingEntity>
      <name/>
    </playingEntity>
  </participantRole>
</participant>
```

Expected Output: Need to add the UNK text value for the self closing empty name element tag.

```
<participant typeCode="LOC">
  <participantRole classCode="SDLOC">
    <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
    <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
    <playingEntity>
      <name>UNK</name>
    </playingEntity>
  </participantRole>
</participant>
```

I need an XSLT script to achieve this requirement.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an identity transformation template:

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

plus a template for the name tag:

```
<xsl:template match="name[not(node())]">
   <name>UNK</name>
</xsl:template>
```

Wrap this within the stylesheet tag, and add an xml header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="name[not(node())]">
   <name>UNK</name>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The will simply change all the name element values to UNK. I want to add a UNK value to name element only when the name element is "self closing empty tag". As in the below case.... this is just a part of XML where the name element is empty else at other places it holds a value.

Comment: The will simply change all the name element values to UNK. I want to add a UNK value to name element only when the name element is "self closing empty tag". As in the below case.... this is just a part of XML where the name element is empty else at other places it holds a value.

<participant typeCode="LOC">
  <participantRole classCode="SDLOC">
    <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
    <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
    <playingEntity>
    <name/>
    </playingEntity>
  </participantRole>
</participant>

Comment: OK. In this case you will need to add a predicate to the select expression: name[not(node())]. I will update my solution.

Comment: Sorry but the solution does not work. The XML does not get transformed.

Comment: which xslt processor are you using? version 1.0 or 2.0? I have just tested with xsltproc, which works fine.

Comment: I agree, if i apply your solution to the chunk of XML code that I have posted here,  the solution work. My original XML is a huge XML file and somehow the solution does not work on the original XML :(

Comment: Could it be that the original XML has namespaces declared and is not using a namespace prefix? If so, then your elements will inherit that namespace and your template for name elements will not match unless it is adjusted to match the namespace that it is bound to(or unless you use a match pattern that works regardless of the namespace, like `match="*[local-name()='name' and not(node())]`.

Comment: Yes the original XML has namespace declaration. I used the match pattern [local-name()='name' and not(node())], but the output xml adds an attribute - <name xmlns="">UNK</name>. This is not recognized by my parser and it throws an error.

Output XML:

<participant typeCode="LOC">
  <participantRole classCode="SDLOC">
    <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
    <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
    <playingEntity>
      <name xmlns="">UNK</name>
    </playingEntity>
  </participantRole>
</participant>

Comment: Thank you for the help I am able to resolve my issue. Please see the below XSLT
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <!--<xsl:template match="name[not(node())]">-->
    <xsl:template match="*[local-name()='name' and namespace-uri() = 'urn:hl7-org:v3' and not(node())]">
        <name>UNK</name>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I have another question with the same issue .. can we modify the above solution, so that it effect the <name/> element present only for a specific xpath?

Comment: you could change the selector to 'playingEntity/name[not(node())]'. Then it will only affect empty name elements wihtin playingEntity. You could also add more ancestor nodes to the XPath expreesion.