# XSLT: Using XSLT script need to transform the XML to its Given OUTPUT xml

Tags: xml, xslt

Original XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc"
    xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <participant typeCode="LOC">
        <participantRole classCode="SDLOC">
            <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
            <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
            <playingEntity>
                <name/>
            </playingEntity>
        </participantRole>
    </participant>
    <Noparticipant typeCode="LOC">
        <NoparticipantRole classCode="SDLOC">
            <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
            <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
            <NoplayingEntity>
                <name/>
            </NoplayingEntity>
        </NoparticipantRole>
    </Noparticipant>
</Document>
```

Output XML should be :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Document xmlns:voc="urn:hl7-org:v3/voc" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc"
    xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:mif="urn:hl7-org:v3/mif"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <participant typeCode="LOC">
        <participantRole classCode="SDLOC">
            <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
            <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
            <playingEntity>
                <name>UNK</name>
            </playingEntity>
        </participantRole>
    </participant>
    <Noparticipant typeCode="LOC">
        <NoparticipantRole classCode="SDLOC">
            <id extension="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" root="1.0"/>
            <addr nullFlavor="UNK"/>
            <NoplayingEntity>
                <name/>
            </NoplayingEntity>
        </NoparticipantRole>
    </Noparticipant>
</Document>
```

So basically we are adding UNK value to self closing empty name element for the playingEntity parent class name element only and we are not disturbing/changing the self closing empty name NoplayingEntity parent class code. The XML also has some namespace declaration, because of which I am having trouble to get this output.

Comment: Please note this is just a small part of a huge XML file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need to add a text value to an self closing empty tag, using XSLT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20505304/i-need-to-add-a-text-value-to-an-self-closing-empty-tag-using-xslt)

Comment: Yes that question was posted by me .. but the requirement here is bit different and I am having hard time figuring it out. Please look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:hl7="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="hl7:playingEntity/hl7:name[not(node())]">
        <xsl:copy>UNK</xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```